# By using AWS Lambda, can we do POST call to public exposed URL

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services

I have a question, can AWS lambda do a POST call to public exposed URL. an trying to do a post call using AWS lambda and i couldn't able to do it. below is my code.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
// TODO implement
callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda');
var request = require('request');
request.post({
headers: {'Authorization' : 'Basic dmF0c2FsLmF2YXN0aGlAc29mdHdhcmVhZy5jb206Zm9vYmFyMTIzNDU='},
url:     'https://foo.webmethodscloud.com/integration/rest/external/integration/submit/development/slackDataLog',
body:    "foo"
})
```

};

Comment: So what happens when you try this? Do you get an error message? Does it just sit there and do nothing?

Comment: @kdgregory,  while executing this code its shows some error. the error I couldn't remember. but I guess, I need to check the VPC console or internet gateway then I should try it again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you check this link on aws:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Thats may happens because of your vpc does not have access to internet.

You should check route table of your vpc console.

https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/

In this console select your vpc and view "Route table".

If your route table does not have internet gateway you can create new internet gateway on VPC console. Then attach it to your route table.

Comment: @Fahri & NicoHaase,  thanks for your valuable answer, as I need to check with VPC console. there is might be a possibility, that internet gateway is not available.